# Query from milliseconds(month,day,year) to milliseconds full date

Tags: mysql

I have records in a Mysql table with their creation date (in milliseconds format).
Now I need a way to create a query where I send a date in milliseconds (but without hours minutes and seconds) and bring me the records of the base that match.

Thank you very much!, and sorry for my English.

Edit:

For example,

My frontend input date has the format MM/DD/YYYY: 11/24/2018 (in milliseconds: 1576033200000)

My db date has the millisecond format:
1576122356000 (in date formate: 11/24/2018 24:45:56)

1576033200000 is different to 1576122356000, But it would need to be taken as equal dates if the day, month and year are the same.

Something like: Select * from X where date = '11/24/2018'.toMilliseconds

query Result:
- 1576122356000

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please put some efforts in framing a question with  relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Yes it will be possible

Comment: Sorry. I just edited and added more information @MadhurBhaiya

Comment: 24 Nov 2018 in UNIX Time is 1543017600 ; so in terms of miliseconds it will be 1543017600000. Where do you get 1576033200000 value from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert 11/24/2018 00:00:00 to milliseconds = 1542997800000
And 11/24/2018 23:59:59 to milliseconds = 1543103999000

And use between to find your result.

Ex.
select * from temp where date between 1542997800000 and 1543103999000